Cannot connect to Next.js Linux HID device
I connected the smartec st-ceo11em proximity card reader device to linux. I added all the permissions I could add and it worked, the connection to the device is there. However, it does not read data from it when I attach the card.
I tried to display the device itself in the console and this is what I got
enter image description here
As I understand it. The device has no support for data input and output. Then I took a different route. In linux itself I decided to see what data comes from the device and used these commands:
sudo cat /dev/hidraw0
When scanning the card, the response came back with this - '''&%!!%&'('''&%!!%&'(
Then I tried a different command:
sudo hexdump -C /dev/hidraw0
The reply came back like this:
00000000  00 00 27 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..'.............|
*
00000030  00 00 26 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..&.............|
00000040  00 00 25 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..%.............|
00000050  00 00 21 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..!.............|
*
00000070  00 00 25 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..%.............|
00000080  00 00 26 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..&.............|
00000090  00 00 27 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..'.............|
000000a0  00 00 28 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..(.............|
000000b0  00 00 27 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..'.............|
*
000000e0  00 00 26 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..&.............|
000000f0  00 00 25 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..%.............|
00000100  00 00 21 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..!.............|
*
00000120  00 00 25 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..%.............|
00000130  00 00 26 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..&.............|
00000140  00 00 27 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..'.............|
00000150  00 00 28 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..(.............|
00000160  00 00 27 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..'.............|
*
00000190  00 00 26 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..&.............|
000001a0  00 00 25 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..%.............|
000001b0  00 00 21 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..!.............|
*
000001d0  00 00 25 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..%.............|
000001e0  00 00 26 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..&.............|
000001f0  00 00 27 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..'.............|
00000200  00 00 28 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..(.............|


And then there's the third team:
sudo od -An -t x1z /dev/hidraw0
Response:
 00 00 27 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >..'.............<
*
 00 00 26 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >..&.............<
 00 00 25 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >..%.............<
 00 00 21 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >..!.............<
*
 00 00 25 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >..%.............<
 00 00 26 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >..&.............<
 00 00 27 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >..'.............<
 00 00 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  >..(.............<


These are some obscure symbols. What could be wrong?

The hexdump you posted looks like input from a fairly typical USB keyboard - consisting of 8-byte reports of the format: modifiers,reserved,key,key,key,key,key,key. The device is transmitting each keystroke as two reports: 8-bytes saying which keys are concurrently pressed, followed by 8-bytes of nulls indicating that no keys are pressed. So the above hexdump is equivalent to: 0 0 0 9 8 4 4 8 9 0 Enter 0 0 0 9 8 4 4 8 9 0 Enter 0 0 0 9 8 4 4 8 9 0 Enter. I would say that the device is working. You should see them if a command window or text editor has the keyboard focus.

@aja Yeah, that's what it is. Can you please tell me the algorithm?

I assume you mean how to translate the key codes to ASCII characters? To do that reliably you would need to parse the HID Report Descriptor, but in this case it appears that the device is using the low byte of the usage codes from the USB Keyboard Page defined in Chapter 10 of the HID Usage Tables document at https://usb.org/document-library/hid-usage-tables-15 ... so 0x27 is '0', 0x28 is '9' etc. Just be aware that some devices may map different numbers to each key (most just behave like this device though).

@aja, Thank you very much for your help. You've been very helpful
